# setTimeout not executing inside of map? or setTimeOut on map function?

Tags: javascript

this is the code:

```
while(countLoop < count) {
  let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*4); // returns // 1 to 3 decimal, this will be used for colors indexes
  console.log("while true count = ",randIndex)
  this.setState(
    ({colorsChallengeForUser}, props) => ({
      colorsChallengeForUser: [...colorsChallengeForUser, randIndex]
    }), 
    () => { // setState has a default callback we make use of that here.
      let { colorsChallengeForUser } = this.state;
        colorsChallengeForUser.map((item, index, array) => {
          switch(item) {
            case 0: 
              // red.play()
              setTimeout(red.play(), 3000);
              break;
            case 1: 
             // green.play()
              setTimeout(green.play(), 3000);
              break;
            case 2: 
             // yellow.play()
              setTimeout(yellow.play(), 3000);
              break;
            case 3: 
             // yellow.play() // this wo
              setTimeout(blue.play(), 3000);
              break;
           defalt: 
              console.error(`Unknown ${item}`);
          }
        });
    }
  );
  countLoop++;
}
```

all works but set time out is not functioning, they all play at the same time upon js evaluation. how do I make map execution slower with setTimeOut?

Comment: `setTimeout(red.play(), 3000);` runs immediately ... `setTimeout(red.play, 3000);` would execute `red.play()` when timeout expires ... P.S. why are you using `.map` when the callback function doesn't return anything? use `.forEach` instead

Comment: Unless `red.play()` returns a function you should follow @JaromandaX advise.

Comment: true (unlikely)

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, will put that in mind. but still setTimeout is not working :/

Comment: really? you've removed the `()`, and it still "doesn't work" ... any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: my bad, i was using map and I tried () => red.play() it didn't work, but using foreach and the callback I did not return it so it's inside only on {} scope

Answer (score 17):

You can use this trick:

```js
var arr = ["apple", "banana", "carrot"];
arr.map( (item, index) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // do stuff function with item
    console.log(item);
  }, 1000*index )
});
```

It will delay each sub function in map 1 second

Answer (score 1):

If all works well and you want time interval use time as `3000,6000,9000`

```
var count = 0;
colorsChallengeForUser.map((item, index, array) => {
    count += 3000;
    switch(item) {
        case 0: 
            // red.play()
            setTimeout(red.play(), count);
        break;
    .......
```

set count as time interval for others as well

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem of direct calling of the functions in the timeout, I suggest to use an array for the object wihout using a `switch ... case` syntax:

```
var options = [red, green, yellow, blue];

// call with
setTimeout(options[item].play, 3000);
//                 ^^^^               index
//                           ^^       without calling the function
```

Comment: don't know why how react handles mp3s, i tried that and returns error that .play() is not a function

Comment: what `typeof` is `play`?